# How do I use the messages file to create my own messagesApi

Tags: playframework-2.6

In my play-framework application, there is a messages file which I can use to define my own messages. Eg

```
##############Application Error messages

error.incorrectBodyType=Incorrect body type. Body type must be JSON
error.incorrectBodyContentInLoginRequest=No Login info found in the request. Check format
error.incorrectUsernameOrPassword = Incorrect username or password
error.unregisteredUser = registration not complete
error.ghostUsername = No record found for the username
error.unauthenticated = You must first sign in
error.unauthorized = You are not permitted

####### Application Success Messages
success.signoutSuccessful = Signout Successful
```

The play frameworks makes these messages available to my `Controller` and I can use them like the `messagesApi("error.unauthenticated")(langs.availables(0))`.

I am unable to figure out how I can use the `messages` file in my unit tests. I am using compile time injection and am creating my own instances of the required classes. To create `MessagesApi`, there is a `DefaultMessagesApi` method but it take a `map`, not a `File`.

I am able to create the messages in my unit tests as follows but I have to duplicate the effort of copying messages from `messages` file to this `map`

```
val messagesApi = new DefaultMessagesApi( //takes map of maps. the first is the language file, the 2nd is the map between message title and description
    Map("en" -> //the language file
      Map("error.incorrectBodyType" -> "Incorrect body type. Body type must be JSON",
        "error.incorrectUsernameOrPassword"->"Incorrect username or password",
        "error.incorrectBodyContentInLoginRequest"->"No Login info found in the request. Check format", //map between message title and description
        "error.unregisteredUser" -> "registration not complete",
        "error.ghostUsername" -> "No record found for the username",
        "success.signoutSuccessful" -> "Signout Successful",
        "error.unauthenticated" -> "You must first sign in",
        "error.unauthorized" -> "You are not permitted")

    )
  )
```

Is there a way I can read the `messages` file and use it in my test case?

Answer (score 0):

My test case already extended `OneAppPerSuiteWithComponents`. I used `components.messagesApi` of `OneAppPerSuiteWithComponents` which was already available and reads from the `messages` file